# React assign key to already rendered component

Tags: reactjs, key, render

Is it possible?

I have a component where children are rendered by an arbitrary mapping function coming in as `props`. A simplified example:

```
class SomeComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    const { renderChild, businessObjects } = this.props
    return <div>
       {businessObjects.map(renderChild)}
    </div>
  }
}
```

I obviously get a warning saying children are rendered without the `key` attribute.

I tried assigning the key after the vdom element is rendered:

```
...
{
  businessObjects.map(e => {
    const vdom = renderChild(e)
    vdom.key = e.id
    return vdom
  })
}
...
```

But the object returned from the JSX transform is frozen, so I can't do this. Also there is no API to temporarily unfreeze then re-freeze objects in js. Cloning is out of question for performance reasons (thousands of components are rendered like this)

**What can I do?**

Again, for performance reason I **can't** wrap the rendered children into another component, so a solution like this wouldn't work:

```
const Child = ({renderChild, bo}) => (<div>{renderChild(bo)}</div>)

// in SomeComponent
...
{
  businessObjects.map(e => (<Child 
    key={e.id}
    bo={e} 
    renderChild={renderChild} 
  />)
  )
}
...
```

**Update**
The reason for this structure is that `SomeComponent` is a dumb component, and has no access to application state (redux). But the rendered children do need to have access to `dispatch` (I do it in a form of connected action creators).

So you can imagine the whole thing like this:

```
const createChildRenderer = ({actionFoo, actionBar}) => (obj) => {
  switch(obj.type) {
    case FOO:
      return <div onClick={() => actionFoo()}>{obj.text}</div>
    case BAR:
      return <div onClick={() => actionBar()}>{obj.text}</div>
    default:
      return null
  }
}
```

And in a connected component

```
@connect(
  ({ businessObjects }) => { businessObjects },
  { actionFoo, actionBar}
)
class SmartComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    const renderChild = createChildRenderer({
      actionFoo: this.props.actionFoo, // action creators
      actionBar: this.props.actionBar
    })
    return (<SomeComponent 
       renderChild={renderChild} 
       businessObjects={this.props.businessObjects}>
  }
}
```

Comment: Where is the renderChild function?

Comment: @VamshiGudipati Not relevant, it's an arbitrary `Object => VDom` function.

Comment: It actually is. You are assigning a key to the vdom object, not to the HTML or to a div that is wrapping your HTML

Comment: @BalázsÉdes, it is actually quite relevant. At least let us see it. It will make this easier to understand.

Comment: I believe what you need is `React.createElement()` (or `React.cloneElement()` if you're creating the element yourself)

Comment: @VamshiGudipati what are you talking about? Have you read the question?

Comment: @OrB Cloning the children looks like a reasonable solution, will have a look at how it works performance-wise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I ended up solving this by taking an actual react component as an argument:

So that in the dumb component that previously took a renderer function, now I take a component:

```
class SomeComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    const { ChildComponent, businessObjects } = this.props
    return <div>
       {businessObjects.map((o) => (<ChildComponent 
           businessObject={o}
           key={o.id}
       />)}
    </div>
  }
}
```

And where I previously created the renderer function, now I create the component:

```
const createChildComponent = ({actionFoo, actionBar}) => 
  ({ businessObject: obj }) => { // this is now a component created dynamically
    switch(obj.type) {
      case FOO:
        return <div onClick={() => actionFoo()}>{obj.text}</div>
      case BAR:
        return <div onClick={() => actionBar()}>{obj.text}</div>
      default:
        return null
    }
}
```

And in the connected component:

```
@connect(
  ({ businessObjects }) => { businessObjects },
  { actionFoo, actionBar}
)
class SmartComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    const ChildComponent = createChildComponent({
      actionFoo: this.props.actionFoo, // action creators
      actionBar: this.props.actionBar
    })
    return (<SomeComponent 
       ChildComponent={ChildComponent} 
       businessObjects={this.props.businessObjects}>
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [cloneElement](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement) on the child received from `renderChild`:

```
React.cloneElement(
  child,
  {...child.props, key: yourKeyValue}
)
```

Comment: There's no need to pass `child.props` to `cloneElement()` as the original props are copied.

Comment: You might want to add some context to this, such as explaining what `cloneElement` does, give an example, etc.